# Matlab make magnitude and angle into complex number

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I have a variable that is holding the magnitude of a complex number and a seperate variable that is holdingthe angle of the complex number. Is there a way I can add the two together to form a polar complex number? or even a way I can make them a rectangular complex number?

Comment: It's just `c = mag.*exp(ang*1i);`. If you need to, you can `mod` the angle to keep it less than `2*pi` to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate function to convert a complex number in polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates would be [`pol2cart`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pol2cart.html).